# Pass a specific instance of a model between views and the controller multiple times without using a form POST

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC5, but very new to it.

Is there a way to pass a specific instance of a model between views and the controller multiple times without using a form POST... for example...

- When the controller is handling the request for the "FirstView" page request, the CarModel class is instantiated and an API call is made on the object to retrieve values from an API and set the object's properties.
- The object is then passed to the "FirstView" page as the model and the properties are displayed for the user to view.
- If the user is happy with the properties, they can then click the ActionLink to save the properties to a database.

I want to pass the entire model object back to the controller so that the work can be done to do the database insert... which I have shown in my controller as "SecondView".

If I am totally off track in terms of how this should be done, please could someone point me in the right direction and link me some reading materials... THANK YOU!

**Here is my model...**

```
public class CarModel
{

    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Colour { get; set; }

    public void GetModelDataFromAPI()
    {
        Make = "BMW";
        Colour = "Black";
        // many other properties, but ommitted for brevity
    }

    public int InsertPropertiesIntoDatabase()
    {
        // code to do the database insert anbd return an ID
        return 1;
    }

}
```

**Here is my FirstView.cshtml...**

```
@model CarsApp.Models.CarModel

<html>
<body>
<h1>First View</h1>
Make: @Model.Make, Colour: @Model.Colour
@Html.ActionLink("Add model properties to database", "SecondView", "Home")
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is my controller...**

```
namespace CarsApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult FirstView()
        {
            CarsApp.Models.CarModel objCarModel = new Models.CarModel();
            objCarModel.GetModelDataFromAPI();
            return View("FirstView", objCarModel);
        }

        public ActionResult SecondView()
        {
            // need to get a reference to the model from the first view
            // then call the insert method of that model, with the properties
            // holding the values from the API
            return Content("ID:" + objCarModel.InsertPropertiesIntoDatabase());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use POST?  Pushing data with a GET is a huge security hole.

Comment: how can I do it with Post then pls

Comment: I think you need to start here, this is the most basic functionality of MVC. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started.  Even using the sample templates will give you a framework you can use to learn from and build on.